# How to give Error message

Tags: android

I did my application in 2.2 version of sdk, so whenever i tried to install my apk in 1.6 or blower version i am getting parser install error. instead of getting parser error is that any change to give our own message..?? i am not sure about this. if it is possible means pls let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should either recompile your app using a lower sdk, which will prevent you from using features not available in 1.6, or when you load whatever is using the offending code, you will have to check to see what version your app is being loaded on and if it is <2.2 (or whatever version started implementing the feature you are using that is higher than 1.6) and not load that code.

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<8) 
        {//Dont load offending stuff or alert user feature not avail;}
     else { //normal behavior;}
```

Comment: Thanks for you replies.. where should i put this in application. Because this function should run at the time of installation.

Comment: You have your targetsdk as set to 2.2 - what do you have your minSDK set to in the manifest?  if you want to load it 1.6, it will have to be set to 4. see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html then you will have to determine which features are using the newer sdk and disable them on old platforms.